# drag and drop of text input boxes using layers of draggable controls

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

My main goal is to be able to drag & drop input boxes of type text
I have scanned the web in order to find a solution and I finally came up with the following one - place a div over the input boxes with a very high opacity so that it wouldnt be shown and a bigger z-index

but none one of the div's style position (absoulote,relative,static or inherit) didnt work for me

this is the html code generated by js:

and this is the code i have added for my multi layers idea:

```
    $('#' + inputID).css('z-index', '5');
    var draggableCtrl = '<div style="height: ' + $('#' + wrapperId).height() + ';width:' + $('#' + wrapperId).width() + ';background-color: blue; position: static; z-index: 10; top :' + pos.top + '; left :' + pos.left + ';"></div>';
    $('#'+wrapperId).append(draggableCtrl);
```

doees anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong?

if you have gotten to here then thanks just for trying :)

Comment: And how do you intend to focus the text boxes and type something into them when you can no longer click them, just using tab ?

Comment: I'll suggest something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dnQ3Q/) ....

Comment: I dont want to focus the text boxes, I receive them with the wanted text, all i need is to drag them, and no this wouldnt work for me - one of my requirements is not to change to original page layout(when i will drag a text box it will duplicate it - I have already succeeded doing it with labels, obviously it was much easier)

Comment: Then why do you need text boxes? Something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dnQ3Q/2/) then, or maybe [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dnQ3Q/3/) ?

Comment: because i receive the text boxes as input - but this one looks more like what I will need - but how can that be that the draggable event of one div effect the outside text box? also i should say that I receive a page with a lot of editboxes and labels that the user will have the ability to drag and drop every one of them...

Comment: The drag event on the overlay is also continuesly updating the position of the input, so it moves along. If you have several input's, it's just a matter of using classes and references correctly, like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dnQ3Q/4/) !!!